# How to create new DIV every 8 MySQL rows queried

Tags: php, sql, html, repeat

im trying to figure out how to create new DIV every 8 MySQL rows queried.  I am integrating jPagination into my site and so I need to create a new DIV container every 8 rows it receives from the database.  Any ideas?

Comment: supply the code that you used to iterates among your query result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this: %

not sure about how your code exactly goes, but in the loop of every row you make a count++ and then something like this which would be in C:

```
if(!count%8) {
   print DIV eccc
}
```

just so you understand what this % does: it gives you the remainer of a division. For example, if your row is number 20, so count equals to 20 at that moment, 20%8 will equal 4. That is because if you divide 20/8 you will have 2.****  something, then multiply 2*8 you get 16. Take 20-16 = 4. So 20%8 is 4. Only when the number in count++ is perfectly divisible by number 8 you will get 0 zero there. So your IF statement says: if there ia no remain dividing count by 8 then do this

maxim

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 1
while( gettingRows )
{
    doWhateverYouDoHere()

    if ( i%8 === 0 )
        print "div"
    ++i

   // or put increment right into the if statement like ( if i++ % 8 === 0 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// previous code.....
$counter = 1;
echo '<div class="outercssclass">';
echo '<div class="innercssclass">';
// fetch mysql query data into $results....
// you can do validations with mysql_num_rows to check the number of rows the query returned
foreach($results as $result) {
    $counter++;
    if($counter % 8 == 0) {
        echo '</div><div class="innercssclass">';  
    }
    // other logic...
    // rest of the code
}    
echo '</div>'; // for closing the inner div
echo '</div>'; // for closing the outer wrapper div

// rest of the program logic...
```